# If I clone a hard disk, are the license keys of the software also cloned?

Tags: hard-drive, license-key

If I clone a hard disk, are the license keys of the software also cloned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But...

Some software uses (and checks) the HDD serial number to generate a hash which is used to compute serial numbers and/or verify that you haven't installed the software on a different computer. Windows does this, although it is more forgiving by allowing changes such as an HDD without you having to re-license. So, keep that in mind. Otherwise, like KaP said, it's a bit-for-bit copy of the old HDD. Everything should be there just as it was in the old HDD. Including corrupted files, if there were any. :-)

Addition: As [per this entry](http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/How-Windows-7-hardware-upgrades-affect-licensing), Windows uses certain hardware components of your system to weigh if a reactivation is needed. The methodology of how it's done is unknown, but the HDD plays a role in it.

Comment: Windows does not check the serial of the HDDs it's installed on.

Comment: But other software does. Punkbuster (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PunkBuster#Published_features) comes to mind as one that uses HDD serial number to ban users from their servers.

Comment: I cloned my hdd dozens of times and never ever been banned by punk buster... And I play a lot of punk buster games

Comment: @Ramhound Are you cheating? If not, then you're not affected. If you are, then you're an exceptional cheater. :-)

Comment: @JSanchez, Hmm, wait back to the original question. So is your answer saying that we can clone a Windows 8.1 and be able to use 2 Windows 8.1 concurrently? Or are you saying that that wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

A clone operation will copy the filesystem, others will copy the drive drive bit-for-bit.  In either case this will usually include any configuration related to licenses.  There are a few applications that will try to do unusual things to hide their keys/activation in places that might not be copied by a typical clone operation, but these are pretty unusual these days.

If the cloned drive will be in a new system, this may not help you though.  Some software links the license to unique details about the hardware the license was initial activated for.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, cloning a disk means all files are copied (simplifying).

It's the same thing if you'd copy the license file.

You have to decide what cloning is: if you have a piece of paper with license-key on it and rewrite it to another piece of paper what will you call it?